# Linq join and group by together on multiple fields and truncate time in date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have following Sql query which joins two table and group by date and user Id

User Table

```
UserName UserId
```

LookupScannedHistory

```
HistoryId UserId ScannedDate ScannedCount
```

I have written following sql query to join table and group by on userId and Scanned Date removing Time varaint

```
SELECT 
      l.[UserID]
      ,CAST([ScannedDate] AS DATE)
      ,Sum([ScannedCount])
      ,[UserName]
  FROM [dbo].[LookupScannedHistory] l
  Join [dbo].[UserMaster] u
  on l.UserID = u.UserId
  group by l.UserId, u.UserName, CAST([ScannedDate] AS DATE)
```

I want to convert this into linq.

I have tried this

```
 (from log in dataContext.LookupScannedHistories
          join user in dataContext.UserMasters
          on log.UserID equals user.UserId 
          where log.ScannedDate >= fiveDayPriorDate
           orderby log.ScannedDate
           group log by new
           {
           ScannedDateOnly = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(log.ScannedDate),
           log.UserID
           } into dateClickedHistory

          select dateClickedHistory                                                                  
        ).ToList();
```

I have done this this gives what I want but I am unable to include username by combining join and group by

Comment: _"I have tried this"_, but what happened next?

Comment: @mshwf I have edited my question. I need help in including username

Comment: Have you tried including `user.UserName` in the group statement?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
var usersReportGroupList = (from log in dataContext.LookupScannedHistories
                            join user in dataContext.UserMasters
                            on log.UserID equals user.UserId 
                            where log.ScannedDate >= fiveDayPriorDate
                            orderby log.ScannedDate
                             group new { user.UserName, log.ScannedCount, 
                              log.ScannedDate} 

                              by new
                              {
                               ScannedDateOnly = 
                             EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(log.ScannedDate),
                             log.UserID,
                             user.UserName
                             } 
                             into dateClickedHistory
                              select dateClickedHistory                                              
                             ).ToList();
   var usersReportList = new List<LookupScannedHistoryDetails>();
                    foreach (var group in usersReportGroupList)
                    {
                        usersReportList.Add(new LookupScannedHistoryDetails()
                        {
                            ScannedCount = group.Sum(x => x.ScannedCount.Value),
                            ScannedDate = group.Key.ScannedDateOnly.Value,
                            UserId = group.Key.UserID.Value,
                            UniqueCount = group.Count(),
                            UserName = group.Key.UserName
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: Hint: You very rarely use "join" in Linq. If your model is well designed you shouldn't ever need to do joins. Just doing "from log in dataContext.LookupScannedHistories" you should be able to get user  like "log.User".